# How do I Redirect live Call from Twilio Flex to Twilio Studio IVR?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I am having problem in transferring the live call. What I have to achieve is, Agent can transfer live call to IVR where IVR ask for rating "Please rate this call from 1-5" and then saves the rating via rest API.

[Here is the first IVR where call is sent to flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JVPD.png)

[Here is the second IVR where flex agent should send the call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19fQ9.png)

I know about Assignment Callback to redirect call to new Twiml document like

```
{
  "instruction": "redirect",
  "call_sid": "CA123456789",
  "url": "http://example.com/assignment_redirect",
}
```

How can I use this to redirect Call to Twilio studio again, In studio all are widgets.

Answer (score 0):

This is only semi-possible right now.

Studio Flow executions are a bit different from normal webhooks that return TwiML, since they MUST be the first webhook hit by the call. (For voice calls, it is also a best practice to make sure the same Studio Webhook is configured as the secondary handler and call status handler for the phone number in question, which suggests that Studio is a bit more robust in how it operates than a typical TwiML App.)

The workaround is to use the `<Dial>` verb to create a *new* call to the Studio Flow that you wish to redirect to. This assumes that each Flow that handles incoming voice has its own phone number(s).

That said, I have been told that a feature request is underway for sometime in 2021 that would allow for different flows to be linked together, so this may change in the future.

I am not exactly sure how you specify a webhook for once the Flex agent is finished with the call -- it looks like you have already done some research into the TaskRouter functionality that enables this. But assuming you can specify a webhook URL (`assignment_redirect` in your example), all you should need to do is create a TwiML Bin containing your `<Dial>` verb to the satisfaction survey Studio flow you want to receive the call, and use that TwiML bin as the webhook URL.

Comment: Do you happen to have any updates on that new feature you said might come out in 2021, or a place where one can monitor the progress of that feature? Thanks!

Comment: @totalhack Nothing I know of. I assume the best thing to do would be to monitor the changelog for Twilio Studio: https://www.twilio.com/changelog?product=studio